# Zmq pub from go using ipc to python subscriber does not work but tcp does

Tags: python, go, ipc, zeromq

I am using go and zmg library github.com/zeromq/goczmq

From go I can send messages to a tcp socket and can be read from python:

In go:

```
pubEndpoint := "tcp://127.0.0.1:7000"
pubSock, err := goczmq.NewPub(pubEndpoint)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer pubSock.Destroy()
pubSock.Bind(pubEndpoint)

for {
    err = pubSock.SendFrame([]byte("stream hello"), goczmq.FlagNone)
}
```

In python:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s"%port)
print ('port:',port)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "stream")

while True:
    transpport = socket.recv()
    transpport = transpport.split('stream ')[1]
    print (transpport)
```

Now if I change from tcp to icp for both I get no errors but the python code is not printing the data.

Now in python publisher and subscriber works over ipc.  I am trying to refactor my publisher to use Go but prefer to use ipc over tcp.

So in sum tcp works from go --> python
Ipc throws no errors but python is not picking up data